# VBA data value not updated to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a macro that will upload data from multiple workbooks to the database. Table will differs based on what type of value/data being inserted. I have there tables. I can insert value in the first table just fine, but when it comes to second table, there's no value inserted, and im using the the exact same code as the first one but with different variables.

```vb
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim connection, insertData As String

connection = "Provider=; Database= Database; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

'open connection
 conn.Open connection

insertData = "INSERT INTO Table2 ([Name], [AScore], [BScore], [CScore], [DScore], [EScore], [FScore]) " & _
             " VALUES ('" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(13, "I").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(11, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(6, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(7, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(3, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(9, "J").Value & "' , '" & _
             SummWb.Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(10, "J").Value & "')"
conn.Execute insertData
conn.close
```

I've tried to see if my code is wrong, and I also tried to drop the table and create a new table, and also using a new workbook to test the code, but the result is still the same. Can you please help to see what is wrong with my code? I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Any runtime errors? No `On Error Resume Next`? Then put a statement `Debug.Print insertData` before the `Execute`, Copy&Paste the statement from the immediate window into Management Studio and execute it from there. What happenes?   And be aware that your code is wide open for SQL Injection - always better to use Parameters for an SQL statement, even if it is a little more code.

Comment: Hi @FunThomas I try to put the debug statement before execute as you said, nothing come out, and also, theres no immediate window is displayed.

Comment: Simpy press Ctrl+G

Comment: Hi @FunThomas after a lot of try and error, the last resort for me was to type again, everything from the beginning, and somehow, it miraculously works. Thanks for your tips! Will use it in the future.

Comment: @user10236952  Were the values in Sheet2 the same after retyping the code?